# SQL Server Insert large float value with precision

Tags: sql-server

When I try to insert value  in row it ends up with different value.

110959910911289**35417748621522300000000** is the number I want column updated with. It ends up converting to 110959910911289**00000000000000000000000** losing digits after 110959910911289

Column type is float (8) with 53 precision

Comment: it should display like 1.10959910911289E+37?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Please see the syntax information about Float data type:

[image]

You can use numeric or decimal data types to get the complete value.

[image]